# My animation suddenly won’t move despite the timeline moving like normal?

Tags: animation, keyframes, timeline

Im very new at blender. I’m doing polygon runway’s 3.0 spaceship loop tutorial. I’m around 14 minutes in at the point where I need to actually animate the ship itself.

At the time, the animation was running smoothly. The ship didn’t move but the walls were animated to move. The next step was to animate the ship moving side to side.

I moved the ship with auto keyframe and I hit play. Somehow, suddenly my entire animation won’t move. The timeline goes forward like usual but the entire scene stays still.

This is probably an easy fix but I just don’t know what to do and, as a newbie, it has me worried.

Comment: Don't get too worried, you should have my "MyFile.blend1" and "MyFile.blend2" backups in your folder that you can recover from.

Comment: maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/